# При запуске скрипта через node.js в termux на android, ничего не происходит

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, typescript, termux

коллеги!

Я написал небольшой сервер на js. Код сервера, к сожалению, выложить не могу.

Проблема заключается в следующем.

При запуске сервера на js через node, ничего не происходит (см. скриншот ниже). **При этом, в процессе разработки, сервер запускался и функционировал корректно, в самом коде производилась только оптимизация функционала.**

[image: Скриншот Termux с телефона (Samsung)]

При этом, запускаю тот же самый файл на Mac - всё работает отлично (см. скриншот ниже)

[image: Скриншот с терминала Mac]

Гипотезы, которые я проверял (и как проверял), при запуске server.js через node в termux:

1. Недостаточно прав на запуск файла server.js.
   **Решение проблемы:** установил максимальные права (на скриншоте видно что server.js имеет максимальные права). К сожалению, не помогло. При запуске файла node молчит.
2. Кодом файла server.js содержит какую-то ошибку.
   **Решение проблемы:** Создал тестовый файл - test.js. Попробовал сразу его запустить (на скриншоте видно). Файл test.js запустился без проблем. Даже учитывая что у него нет прав на исполнение.
   Содержимое файла test.js простое:

   console.log("node js runned");
3. Возможно, я забыл закинуть новую версию сервера (server.js) на смартфон, а текущая, содержит какую-то ошибку.
   **Решение проблемы:** Закидываю новую версию файла, которая отлично запускается на Mac. Пробую запустить сервер (server.js) на смартфоне. И снова ничего не происходит.
4. Вдруг, порты на которых пытается запуститься сервер (server.js) в termux, уже заняты какой-то другой программой на смартфоне?
   **Решение проблемы:** При такой ситуации, во время запуска сервера он покажет что порты уже заняты. При разработке функционала, такая ситуация рассматривалась. В этом случае, сервер выдал бы сообщение о том что порты заняты. Поэтому, такой вариант тоже исключается.
5. Вдруг, не совпадает версия node. Версия node действительно не совпадает. На Mac установлена 18.13.0 а на смартфоне 19.6.1.
   **Решение проблемы:** Проверяю что при в новой версии node ничего не добавили нового, что могло бы сломать функционал. Ничего особого не нахожу. Удаляю версию на смартфоне и устанавливаю версию node 18.13.0. Через команду apt install nodejs-lte (последняя 18.13.0). Проверяю, что версия соответствует. Запускаю файл server.js, но ничего не меняется. Результат ровно такой же как и был до этого.
6. Сервер был написан на TypeScript. И преобразован в js. Подразумеваю что что-то могло пойти не так. Но опять же, файл запускается на Mac и не запускается на смартфоне ( в termux-е).

Буду очень благодарен, за любую подсказку, что ещё может быть.

Заранее извиняюсь, если подобрал не очень подходящие теги.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось разобраться с ошибкой путём поэтапной отладки кода (вывода console.log на каждом этапе запуска скрипта). Выяснил, что скрипт всё же запускается, но что-то происходит внутри скрипта. Дошёл до участка кода где логируются ошибки во время запуска сервера. Оказалось, что в том случае, если 80 порт занят, в node (под termux) выводится следующая ошибка: `Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80`, она говорит о том, что недостаточно прав для запуска (ошибка `EACCES`). Но на самом деле, по какой-то причине нельзя занять 80 порт (до этого, порт успешно занимался, почему так произошло, предстоит ещё выяснить). Обычно, в такой ситуации выводится ошибка о том, что порт уже занят (ошибка `EADDRINUSE`). А никаких сообщений при запуске скрипта не выводилось потому, что для реакции на разные ошибки, используется событие по работе с ошибками (сервер написан на стандартном модуле nodejs - http). Продемонстрирую часть кода, в который был написан неправильно:

```
server.on('error', (e) => {
            // @ts-ignore
            if(e.code === 'EADDRINUSE') { // Отслеживалась только эта ошибка
                APIServer.logging.system('Address or port in use, retrying...', server.address());
                setTimeout(() => {
                    server.close();
                    server.listen(APIServer.port);
                }, 5000);
            }
            // По собственной невнимательности, забыл добавить сюда else с выводом других ошибок...
        });
```

Теперь, код выглядит так:

```
server.on('error', (e) => {
        // @ts-ignore
        switch (e.code) {
            case 'EADDRINUSE':
                APIServer.logging.system('Address or port in use, retrying...', server.address());
                setTimeout(() => {
                    server.close();
                    server.listen(APIServer.port);
                }, 5000);
            break;
            case 'EACCES':
                APIServer.logging.system('The server cannot be started. Permission denied. Try to choose a different port! Current port:', APIServer.port);
                server.close();
            break;
            default:
                APIServer.logging.system('Error:', e.message);
                server.close();
            break;
        }
    });
```

Как итог, если кто-то столкнётся с такой же (или похожей) проблемой, не забывайте отлаживать код. Вероятнее всего он запускается, просто не предусмотрен вывод сообщений, из-за отлова событий, в случае ошибки. Думал, никогда на такое не попадусь и вот, попался :)

Answer (score 0):

Termux не работает с низкоуровневыми функциями Android без наличии Root-прав. Попробуйте получить Root-права на ваше устройство (инструкция для вашего устройства находится на 4PDA, в качестве средства получения Root-прав обычно используется Magisk, хотя раньше использовали SuperUser и SuperSU). Ещë необходимо на всякий случай отключить SELinux, иначе будут проблемы (это также гуглится на 4PDA). В итоге проблема будет решена.

Comment: Добавил информацию в свой вопрос о том, что сервер во время разработки запускался и функционировал. В дополнение к этому, есть стати в интернете, пишут свой сервер на js и запускают его через node в termux (https://habr.com/ru/post/301442/). Ситуации, в которой нужно получать права на смартфон, хотелось бы избежать, так как сервер будет предназначен для общего пользования. Возможно, есть ещё какие-то мысли на этот счёт? В любом случае, спасибо за ответ!